# How to avoid flipping of the object attached to the main camera in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mirroring

https://mega.nz/file/zUY0HYbL#ahwM_uGlp7-5iMLFjR1uaj6hgeVpjyhB3SCLe9xAt88 this is my project. I have an issue with the heatlhbar mirroring. I attached heatlhbar to the main camera and my character. When character flips, the healthbar flips too. Character flipping I based on the scale of the player - when player is facing left, the scale is less than zero.

I tried to write some flipping script, but it did not work - when I change the x value, healthbar disapears - the code is in this situation bad, it does not work, because how I mentioned before, when I change the x scale value, it disapers, so I cannot do it using c#. I need to do it somehow.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Don't expect anyone to download and look through your project, we aren't freelancers. Include the relevant code and screenshots, please.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to flip the player without effecting the healthbar. Then you need to seperate thoose 2 Objects. I'm guessing that the healthBar is parented to your Player and because you change the localScale of the player the healthBar flips as well.

If you seperate thoose 2 Objects you should be able to flip the Player without affecting the HealthBar.

As an example you could make a Player GameObject that has all the Code and 2 Children as well which are HealthBar and PlayerGrahpics. You can then calls HealthBar and the Graphisc via. `GetComponentFromChildren();` and then just flip the Graphics GameObject.